# Opening YouTube videos according to chakra cycles

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, windows, configuration

I'm learning how to write code in Python. This code makes an .ini that saves different cycles adding one new operation to the previous cycle.  It starts at 1;1, saves that it has run 1 cycle and will start cycle 2 next time. So, next is 1;2 followed by 2;2. Next cycle is 3, so it will go up to three: 1;3, 2;3, 3;3, etc. until 7;7 is reached. After that it switches to fullcycles. Hope this explains it well enough.

The challenge is to make this code work with as least as code as possible.

```
import os, configparser, webbrowser


chakras = [['root', '1', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTqktSAmG30'], 
           ['sacral', '2', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRGs0GiR-QY'], 
           ['solar', '3', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pz47Fv_TQDU'], 
           ['heart', '4', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDWoIAITBiY'], 
           ['throat', '5', 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwzSOF9GEHo'], 
           ['thirdeye', '6', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpbXlN2duKk'], 
           ['crown', '7', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZpUUXNQW1E']]

def OpenChakraLinkPlusSaveNext():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('Chakras.ini')
    config.sections()
    try:
        chakracycle = int(config['Chakras']['chakracycle'])
        trainingcycle = int(config['Chakras']['trainingcycle'])
        fullchakracycle = int(config['Chakras']['fullchakracycle'])

    except KeyError:
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config['Chakras'] = {'chakracycle': 1,
                             'trainingcycle': 1,
                             'fullchakracycle': 0}
        with open('Chakras.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('Chakras.ini')
        config.sections()

    chakracycle = int(config['Chakras']['chakracycle'])
    trainingcycle = int(config['Chakras']['trainingcycle'])
    fullchakracycle = int(config['Chakras']['fullchakracycle'])

### Debugging which cycle is saved now.
##    print(chakracycle)
##    print(trainingcycle)
##    print(fullchakracycle)

    for chakra in chakras:
        if int(chakra[1]) == chakracycle:
            ### Debugging which chakra is going to be loaded.
            ##print(chakra[0])
            webbrowser.open(chakra[2])

    if fullchakracycle == 0:
        if chakracycle >= 7 and trainingcycle == chakracycle:
            config['Chakras'] = {'chakracycle': 1,
                                 'trainingcycle': 0,
                                 'fullchakracycle': int(fullchakracycle) + 1}
            with open('Chakras.ini', 'w') as configfile:
                config.write(configfile)

        elif trainingcycle == chakracycle:
            config['Chakras'] = {'chakracycle': 1,
                                 'trainingcycle': int(trainingcycle) + 1,
                                 'fullchakracycle': 0}
            with open('Chakras.ini', 'w') as configfile:
                config.write(configfile)

        elif trainingcycle != chakracycle:
            config['Chakras'] = {'chakracycle': int(chakracycle) + 1,
                                 'trainingcycle': int(trainingcycle),
                                 'fullchakracycle': 0}
            with open('Chakras.ini', 'w') as configfile:
                config.write(configfile)

    elif fullchakracycle != 0:
        if chakracycle >= 7:
            config['Chakras'] = {'chakracycle': 1,
                                 'trainingcycle': 0,
                                 'fullchakracycle': int(fullchakracycle) + 1}
            with open('Chakras.ini', 'w') as configfile:
                config.write(configfile)

        else:
            config['Chakras'] = {'chakracycle': int(chakracycle) + 1,
                                 'trainingcycle': 0,
                                 'fullchakracycle': int(fullchakracycle)}
            with open('Chakras.ini', 'w') as configfile:
                config.write(configfile)

### Debugging which cycle will be saved.
##    print(chakracycle)
##    print(trainingcycle)
##    print(fullchakracycle)

OpenChakraLinkPlusSaveNext()
```

Answer (score 5):

`OpenChakraLinkPlusSaveNext()` is a *very* long function, with its logic for incrementing, loading, and saving state scattered and duplicated all over the place.  Functions should adhere to the Single Responsibility Principle, and do one thing only.

Another problem is that the implementation is strongly tied to `configparser`.  As a result, you need to put `int()` casts all over the place, because `configparser` only deals with strings.

### Counting

Start by focusing on the core functionality and the main challenge of the code, which is how to increment the counters.

I suggest defining a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) with three fields: `fullchakracycle`, `trainingcycle`, and `chakra`.  Note that I've written the fields in reverse order, because `fullchakracycle` acts as the "most significant" field if you wanted to compare two states.  I've also renamed `chakracycle` to `chakra`, since I consider it just a counter and not a cycle counter.

```
from collections import namedtuple

class ChakraState(namedtuple('ChakraState', 'fullchakracycle trainingcycle chakra')):
    def next(self):
        if self.fullchakracycle or \
           self.trainingcycle == self.chakra == 7:
            return ChakraState(
                self.fullchakracycle + (self.chakra == 7),
                0,
                self.chakra % 7 + 1
            )
        else:
            return ChakraState(
                0,
                self.trainingcycle + (self.chakra == self.trainingcycle),
                self.chakra % self.trainingcycle + 1
            )
```

You can easily write a short script to verify that it increments correctly:

```
state = ChakraState(0, 1, 1)
for _ in range(50):
    print(state)
    state = state.next()
```

The output should look like:

```
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=1, chakra=1)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=2, chakra=1)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=2, chakra=2)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=3, chakra=1)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=3, chakra=2)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=3, chakra=3)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=4, chakra=1)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=4, chakra=2)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=4, chakra=3)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=4, chakra=4)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=5, chakra=1)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=5, chakra=2)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=5, chakra=3)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=5, chakra=4)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=5, chakra=5)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=6, chakra=1)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=6, chakra=2)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=6, chakra=3)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=6, chakra=4)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=6, chakra=5)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=6, chakra=6)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=7, chakra=1)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=7, chakra=2)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=7, chakra=3)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=7, chakra=4)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=7, chakra=5)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=7, chakra=6)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=0, trainingcycle=7, chakra=7)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=1, trainingcycle=0, chakra=1)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=1, trainingcycle=0, chakra=2)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=1, trainingcycle=0, chakra=3)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=1, trainingcycle=0, chakra=4)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=1, trainingcycle=0, chakra=5)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=1, trainingcycle=0, chakra=6)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=1, trainingcycle=0, chakra=7)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=2, trainingcycle=0, chakra=1)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=2, trainingcycle=0, chakra=2)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=2, trainingcycle=0, chakra=3)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=2, trainingcycle=0, chakra=4)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=2, trainingcycle=0, chakra=5)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=2, trainingcycle=0, chakra=6)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=2, trainingcycle=0, chakra=7)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=3, trainingcycle=0, chakra=1)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=3, trainingcycle=0, chakra=2)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=3, trainingcycle=0, chakra=3)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=3, trainingcycle=0, chakra=4)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=3, trainingcycle=0, chakra=5)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=3, trainingcycle=0, chakra=6)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=3, trainingcycle=0, chakra=7)
ChakraState(fullchakracycle=4, trainingcycle=0, chakra=1)
```

### Suggested solution

Then, we can go on to add support for loading and saving the state in `Chakras.ini`.  I've chosen to write the `load()` and `save()` methods within the `ChakraState` class.

`chakras` is a "constant", so I'd name it using `ALL_CAPS`.  Since only the URLs matter, I've dropped the name and number fields.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import configparser
import webbrowser

CHAKRAS = [
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTqktSAmG30', # root
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRGs0GiR-QY', # sacral
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pz47Fv_TQDU', # solar
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDWoIAITBiY', # heart
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwzSOF9GEHo', # throat
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpbXlN2duKk', # thirdeye
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZpUUXNQW1E', # crown
]

class ChakraState(namedtuple('ChakraState', 'fullchakracycle trainingcycle chakra')):
    def next(self):
        if self.fullchakracycle or \
           self.trainingcycle == self.chakra == len(CHAKRAS):
            return ChakraState(
                self.fullchakracycle + (self.chakra == len(CHAKRAS)),
                0,
                self.chakra % len(CHAKRAS) + 1
            )
        else:
            return ChakraState(
                0,
                self.trainingcycle + (self.chakra == self.trainingcycle),
                self.chakra % self.trainingcycle + 1
            )

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, filename):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(filename)
        try:
            return cls(**{k: int(v) for k, v in config['Chakras'].items()})
        except KeyError:
            return cls(0, 1, 1)

    def save(self, filename):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config['Chakras'] = self._asdict()
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            config.write(f)

def open_chakra_link_and_save_next():
    state = ChakraState.load('Chakras.ini')
    webbrowser.open(CHAKRAS[state.chakra - 1])
    state.next().save('Chakras.ini')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    open_chakra_link_and_save_next()
```

Comment: nice solution. In python 3.7, [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) might be easier than `namedtuple`

Comment: Wow Thanks, man I'm sorry I couldn't take the time to respond and figure out how well written your script is. I still haven't tried it out, but thanks in advance man, this is literally what I've asked for!